# Android, add radiobuttons in for-loop

Tags: java, android, view, for-loop, radio-button

I am currently developing an Android 1.5 app.
I'm asking all the results of a query from my `sqlite` db and for every result I want to add a `RadioButton` to my `RadioGroup`.

```
private void prepFilialen(){
    List<Filiaal> lstFilialen = this.dh.getAllFilialen();
    RadioGroup rdgrpFilialen = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
    for(int i = 0;i<=lstFilialen.size()-1;i++){
        RadioButton rdbtn = new RadioButton(this);
        rdgrpFilialen.addView(rdbtn);
        rdbtn.setId(i);
        rdbtn.setText(lstFilialen.get(i).getFil_Naam());
    }
}
```

This causes the app to crash. I want to add text to the `RadioButtons` and add an ID to them and work further with the ID of the selected `RadioButton`.

Is this possible?
Is this perhaps simpler when using a `Spinner ( = ComboBox)` instead of `RadioButtons`?

DDMS Error report:

```
05-31 18:03:47.345: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1040): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
05-31 18:03:47.375: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1040): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-31 18:03:47.375: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1040):     at com.totsp.androidexamples.Main.prepFilialen(Main.java:66)
05-31 18:03:47.375: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1040):     at com.totsp.androidexamples.Main.access$1(Main.java:61)
05-31 18:03:47.375: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1040):     at com.totsp.androidexamples.Main$2.onClick(Main.java:54)
05-31 18:03:47.375: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1040):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2179)
05-31 18:03:47.375: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1040):     at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:3828)
05-31 18:03:47.375: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1040):     at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6291)
05-31 18:03:47.375: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1040):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3368)
05-31 18:03:47.375: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1040):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
05-31 18:03:47.375: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1040):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
05-31 18:03:47.375: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1040):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
05-31 18:03:47.375: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1040):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
05-31 18:03:47.375: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1040):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1707)
05-31 18:03:47.375: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1040):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1197)
05-31 18:03:47.375: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1040):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:1993)
05-31 18:03:47.375: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1040):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1691)
05-31 18:03:47.375: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1040):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1525)
05-31 18:03:47.375: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1040):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-31 18:03:47.375: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1040):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-31 18:03:47.375: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1040):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
05-31 18:03:47.375: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1040):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-31 18:03:47.375: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1040):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-31 18:03:47.375: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1040):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
05-31 18:03:47.375: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1040):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
05-31 18:03:47.375: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1040):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

private void prepFilialen(){
    List<Filiaal> lstFilialen = this.dh.getAllFilialen();
    RadioGroup rdgrpFilialen = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);

    for(int i = 0;i<=lstFilialen.size()-1;i++){

        RadioButton rdbtn = new RadioButton(this);

        rdgrpFilialen.addView(rdbtn);

        rdbtn.setId(i);

        rdbtn.setText(lstFilialen.get(i).getFil_Naam());
    }
}
```

Is this perhaps possible using a `spinner` instead of `radiobuttons`?

Comment: Please, provide stack trace from logcat output.

Comment: thank you for comment, error report added

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void prepFilialen(){
List<Filiaal> lstFilialen = this.dh.getAllFilialen();
RadioGroup rdgrpFilialen = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
RadioButton rdbtn;
for(int i = 0;i<=lstFilialen.size()-1;i++){
    rdbtn = new RadioButton(this);
    rdgrpFilialen.addView(rdbtn);
    rdbtn.setId(i);
}
```

}

Try that. And let me know what those line numbers are that you've posted. That would help me a lot. I did something like this with EditTexts and had a similar issue to you.

Comment: Thanks for the response, line numbers added now.

    private void prepFilialen(){
     List<Filiaal> lstFilialen = this.dh.getAllFilialen();
     RadioGroup rdgrpFilialen = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
     for(int i = 0;i<=lstFilialen.size()-1;i++){
      RadioButton rdbtn = new RadioButton(this);
      rdgrpFilialen.addView(rdbtn);
      rdbtn.setId(i);
      rdbtn.setText(lstFilialen.get(i).getFil_Naam());
     }
    }

Still gives the same Exception, I checked the size of my List it's 3, as it should be.